# "npm run build" compiling errors when fired on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, next.js, server

Trying to build my project on my Ubuntu server, it seems that the compiler runs a slightly different version of JS that what my machine can read... (its on a VPS from IONOS, running Ubuntu Jammy)

- Cloning the repos: OK
- Installing all the dependencies: OK
- Updating all necessaries files (.env.local, ...): OK
- Building app with "npm run build": creates error:

```
/repos/template_next-app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js:257
            showAll: args["--show-all"] ?? false,
                                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.dev (/home/samuel/repos/template_next-app/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js:15:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/samuel/repos/template_next-app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:150:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

It seems like it can't read some JS comparator, such as the "??".
So I've tried to change them for the "||" and that got rid of some issues.

However, I keep running into some other issue: after the "??", it is a dependency not detected (the line `const { fetch } = require("next/dist/compiled/undici");` from another file is causing a compiling error as well...

Anyway, I figured maybe some of you have encountered issues of the same sorts and have, hopefully, figured it out ?

That would be great ! :D

I'm expecting to have to upgrade something to make it understand the compiler from nextJS.
My knowledge being remarkably low on this subject, I'm open to any proposition on what and how to do it.

Perfect goal would be:

- install that
- run this
- npm run buil
  : build complete!

On the machine I have installed:

Node version v14.21.3 (edit of 6/8/2023)

NPM version 8.5.1

Let me know if anything else is required for you to help me out :D

Comment: Bump your Node.js version to 14+.

Comment: I did but... still the same error...

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='`

`samuel@localhost:~/repos/template_next-app$ node --version
v14.21.3`


Nice try ! :D

Comment: Here what fixes it (I have to do this every run on the server)

Answer (score 0):

Here what solves it:
To resolve this issue, you need to upgrade your Node.js version on the Ubuntu 22.04 server to at least 16.6.0 or higher. Here's how you can do it:
Remove the existing version of Node.js and npm (if any):
bash
sudo apt remove nodejs npm
Install Node Version Manager (nvm) for managing Node.js versions:
bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
Close and reopen your terminal, or run the following command to apply the changes:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Install Node.js 16.x using nvm:

```
nvm install 16
```

Set the installed Node.js version as the default:

```
nvm use 16
```

Verify that the correct Node.js version is now in use:

```
node -v
```

Now, you should have Node.js version 16.x in use.
To confirm, you can run node -v and it should show a version greater than or equal to 16.6.0.